# Selenium WebDriver -- XPath

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, xpath

[image]

Trying to get the script to select the filter button on the top but can't seem to figure out how to input the XPath. I believe it has something to do with it be in a separate iframe.

```js
package chromebrowser;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class JavaClass {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Newfolder\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://mlvtwrew73.consilio.com/Relativity/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  //Thread.sleep(5000); this can be used as a wait command before moving on to the next function
  
  WebElement objWE;
  Thread.sleep(9000);
  // objWE = driver.findElement(By.linkText("User Status"));
  // objWE.click();

  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(\"ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch\")")).click();
   
  // objWE = driver.findElement(By.id("1"));
  
  // driver.close(); will be used to close the site once all testing completes

 }

}
```

Comment: if it is in a separate frame, you need to switchTo() that frame, then execute the xpath again.

Comment: so I added this to the script but still got the same error:  driver.switchTo().frame("ListTemplateFrame");
  
     driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(\"ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch\")/img[1]")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ID locator -- it's more appropriate here (and faster than XPath):

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ct‌l00_ctl00_itemList_F‌​ilterSwitch")));
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch")).click();
```

Comment: Thats what I was initially using but did not seem to work so I figured I would go with xpath. I tried the above and unfortunately didnt work did you need anything else from me that can help? Thanks

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch"}

Comment: @Jesus, use `WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch")));` before doing click action.

Comment: Sorry but confused on where it is you want me to input this?

Comment: okay so i figured it out. here is what i did similar to what you were asking me to do ........                                              driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ListTemplateFrame\"]")));
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch\"]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

I need more clarity regarding your question. 
As I have understand, I think you need a requirement of XPath of the Filters image. If i am right, try this:

```
//div[@class='actionCellContainer']//a/img[@class='itemListActionImage']
```

Comment: clarifying: so the script is opening up the page but when it goes to clicking on the filter icon. It does nothing. I tried to embedd the xpath of the button but that did not seem to work. I researched on google a bit and have seen a couple of other ppl running into the same issue as well and having to do something with the element being in a separate iframe. but failed to explain how they resolved it. I tried the above and did not work. Is there anything else I can provide you that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing in an incorrect XPath. Try this one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch']")).click();
```

Comment: Yeah i have tried this snippet before and did not work tried it just now again but console says Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='actionCellContainer']//a/img[@class='itemListActionImage']"}

Comment: You aren't using the XPath that I recommended. It shows the XPath that you tried to use was :"//div[@class='actionCellContai‌​ner']//a/img[@class=‌​'itemListActionImage‌​']. I told you to use "//a[@id='ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch']".

Comment: whoops probably replied to the wrong thread. My bad.. here is the correct error yours gave me:                                                                                      no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch']"}

Comment: solution: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ListTemplateFrame\"]")));
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch\"]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

If there is then why you are using xpath.

Use id like this

```
  driver.findElment(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_itemList_FilterSwitch"). click ();
```